# In 16-bit MS-DOS, how do I get a file handle to the currently running .exe?

Tags: ms-dos, programming

The context is that I have additional data in the .exe file and wish to access it.

I know this is possible, as plenty of programs would store extra data after the loadable part of an MZ .exe — most 32-bit programs would do this; the 16-bit part would set up the DPMI environment and then load the bulk of the data from the rest of the file. But to do this, I need to know where the file is. I'd expect there to be some reference (either a file handle or an old-fashioned FCB) in the PSP, but there's nothing I can find. I *have* found a few suggestions that it's passed in in the environment somewhere, but can't find a definitive reference...

Comment: After the environment's double-NUL byte (which marks the end of the regular variables) there may be a word with the value 1. Following that word there will then be an ASCIZ string with the executed pathname. You will have to open this with 21.3D or 21.6C yourself. Also answered in https://www.bttr-software.de/forum/forum_entry.php?id=17398

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*[Edit: Ooops, that question already been answered a few years ago on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53571943)]*

> I'd expect there to be some reference (either a file handle or an old-fashioned FCB) in the PSP, but there's nothing I can find.

Almost. While there is no file handle or FCB to the program file, as it is already closed before execution starts, DOS (starting with 3.0) stores the program name as ASCIZ within the environment memory block, right after all environment variables.

To retrieve

- Test for min DOS version 3.0
- Get PSP address from DOS
- Get the environment segment from offset 002Ch of the PSP
- Advance to after the last environment variable

  - marked by two consecutive null bytes
- There's a word with the number of strings following
- If at least 1, the program name follows
- Fetch the program name (a full ASCIZ path name)
- Open that file
- Do whatever you want to do :))

This works for .COM and .EXE programs - but only with DOS 3.0 and above.

---

In Assembly (COM or EXE) this may look a bit like:

```
    MOV   AH,30h         ; Get DOS version
    INT   21h
    JC    LOWDOS         ; Call failed -> DOS 1.x ?
    CMP   AL,3           ; At least DOS 3
    JAE   DOSOK          ; Yes -> continue
LOWDOS:  ; DOS version too low: terminate with exit code = 126
    MOV   AX,4C7Eh       ; Try to do it DOS 2 style
    INT   21h
    INT   20h            ; Just in case this is really DOS 1.x
DOSOK:
    MOV   AH,51h         ; Get active PSP
    INT   21h            ; Will never return an error
    MOV   ES,BX          ; Segment of PSP
    MOV   AX,ES:[2Ch]    ; Get Environment Segment from PSP
    MOV   ES,AX          ; to ES
    XOR   DI,DI          ; Point ES:DI at start of environment vars
    XOR   AX,AX          ; Search for 0-bytes
    CLD                  ; Upward
    MOV   CX,32767       ; Maximum size of an environment segment
SKIPVAR:
;Loop skipping all environment variables
    REPNE SCASB          ; Skip a string
    JCXZ  NFND           ; Searched max.length without finding a zero
    CMP   AL,BYTE ES:[DI] ; next byte as well Zero ?
    JNE   SKIPVAR        ; No -> Skip next var
    INC   DI             ; Skip over zero byte
    CMP   WORD ES:[DI],AX; String count not zero ?
    JE    NFND           ; No -> Not Found
    INC   DI             ; Skip string count
    INC   DI
FOUND:
; Full Program Name at ES:DI
; Do whatever is to be done
; like opening it via 3Dh:

    PUSH  DS
    MOV   AX,ES
    MOV   DS,AX
    MOV   DX,DI           ; Filename in DS:DX
    MOV   AL,<openmode>   ; Read/Write/etc...
    MOV   CL,0
    MOV   AH,3Dh          ; Open File
    INT   21h
    POP   DS
    JNC   FILE_OPENED
; Open Error: terminate with exit code = openerror code 
    MOV   AH,4Ch
    INT   21h
NFND:
; Name Not Found: terminate with exit code = 127
    MOV   AX,4C7Fh
    INT   21h

FILE_OPENED:
; Read or write from/to the program file
; File Handle in AX

    ...

    END
```

Rather easy, isn't it?

Comment: Actually, this "feature" was never documented anywhere, so it's not in the list of officially supported MSDOS-APIs - I can still confirm it works well with any DOSes starting from 3.3 to 6.0. While MSDOS is unlikely to change much during the next few years ( ;) ), your mileage using many of the non-MS DOSes (like DRDOS or OS/2) might vary.

Comment: @tofro very true. Still it's the most clean way I know. Of course one can go ahead, retrieve the path variable and search along that, in hope to find its own program among -  works mostly as long as it hasn't been renamed. Past DOS 4 looking at the MCB will provide a hint at the name DOS used/found. Still, all rather clumsy.

Comment: DR DOS and OS/2 store the executable path in the same location after the environment variables. I think this was even documented in the DR DOS system programming manual.

Comment: Wow, that's awful. But then, this is DOS, so I'm not sure what I was expecting... I have, BTW, tracked down the DJGPP exe stub loader, which has a full production quality example: https://www.delorie.com/bin/cvsweb.cgi/djgpp/src/stub/stub.asm?rev=1.8 One fun gotcha is that the program may be run with no free file handles, making it impossible to open the exe unless you free some up first!

Comment: @DavidGiven oh, that' serious bad code - including 'fake' instructions to save a single byte. What are they thinking - if at all...?

Comment: "It's cool to fix bugs, but not as great to change program logic." I wonder about this. Is having redundancies a good thing in this code snippet? If changes like this are a no go, then I'll have to respect your view on the matter in future. It's still a good answer though, since *I* felt the desire to improve it further.

Comment: @SepRoland I love any bug found, and the loading of AH was most definite one. The other correction adds an assumption about DS, which I avoided on purpose. The way it is it only assumed CS to be at PSP. Call it a pet peeve of mine, but I always try to reduce assumptions (Yes, I know CS is set). In fact, even using CS isn't what I like here. Normally I would do INT21 51h or 61h GET PSP. Using COM and CS was to avoid covering the important parts with too much code - maybe I should change that, what's your opinion?

Comment: Your desire to keep it simpler was already in the mention `ORG 100h` that will produce a .COM program where all 4 segment registers will be equal to each other. Therefore reading from the PSP would never require any segment override prefix. I agree about trying to reduce assumptions, but in case of a .COM file the assumptions about CS and DS are already fixed. Not having the `CS:` override and removing the `ORG 100h` would even yield valid code for an .EXE program as then DS automatically points at the PSP totally different from CS.

Comment: About `JC LOWDOS ; Call failed -> DOS 1.x ?`: I don't think that the GetDOSVersionNumber function returns any carry flag, so it might be dangerous to leave `JC` in! For DOS versions earlier than 2.0 my manual says that a version number of zero would be returned.

Comment: @SepRoland MS-DOS version 1 style error return is CF unchanged, al = 0. This is why function 71h subfunctions are said to return the code 7100h in ax when no LFN interface is installed, it is by default the CF unchanged al = 0 return. (Some handlers do now return CY al = 0 though, to harden things.)

Comment: @SepRoland Checking Carry is the definite way to detect faulty (including not supported) DOS calls. No other way should be used (by default). Not sure what manual you use, but prior to DOS 2 Function 30h was not defined, thus will not return anything. MS-DOS guarantees since V1 that any function number higher than the highest supported returns with AL=0 CF=1 (Also see [sources](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v1.25/source/MSDOS.ASM#L270)). Checking CF in turn is the least risky way to go ahead as it covers any other error as well.

Comment: @SepRoland It seems as I couldn't make myself clear. I never claimed about being 'simple', but keeping assumptions low. Taking it for granted that something is given is the exact opposite - and the best way to create portage problems, which I try to avoid by default. My rule is to use only resources that I can't do without. Also, COM style was used for maximum compatibility. (let me add the mentioned changes :)

Comment: The manual I use is the 1989 DOS Programmer's Reference by Terry Dettmann and Jim Kyle. Using function 51h is the robust way to reach the PSP in case segment registers would have been changed in the mean time. Incidentally, I see that your last edit forgot `int 21h` for the function 51h!

Comment: @SepRoland Drats thank you. I added the comment about no error being generated in a second though and might have destroyed that instruction. Lesson to learn: Documentation is evil :)) (For older DOS I go by the DOS Encyclopedia, for newer by teh 5.0 manual by MS-Press)

Answer (score 14):

If definitive references is what you’re looking for, the usual one to consult is [the RBIL](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2126.html#table-01379):

> ```
> Format of Program Segment Prefix (PSP):
> Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01378)
> […]
>  2Ch    WORD    DOS 2+ segment of environment for process (see #01379)
> […]
>
>
> Format of environment block:
> Offset  Size    Description     (Table 01379)
>  00h  N BYTEs   first environment variable, ASCIZ string of form "var=value"
>       N BYTEs   second environment variable, ASCIZ string
>         ...
>       N BYTEs   last environment variable, ASCIZ string of form "var=value"
>         BYTE    00h
> ---DOS 3.0+ ---
>         WORD    number of strings following environment (normally 1)
>       N BYTEs   ASCIZ full pathname of program owning this environment
>                 other strings may follow
> ```

As this is a pathname and not an already-open handle, you will have to open the file yourself, which is of course subject to the usual race conditions.  (Not that anyone cares about such things when writing for DOS.)

Comment: What usual race conditions do you mean? What race conditions there could even be?

Comment: Someone could've deleted or renamed or replaced the program file between the time when your program was launched and the time when you (re)open the file. Not a major concern on a single-user OS like MS-DOS, but there have been many security issues caused by such race conditions on multi-user systems, like the famous [Unix setuid script vulnerability](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts).